# Не понимаю почему не удается скрыть элемент при помощи свойства hidden

Tags: javascript, html

Здраствуйте!
Буду краток, у меня есть масив элементов (В данном случае кнопок), которым я в цикле присваиваю ID, пример: "id1", "id2", "id3"...

```
for (var i = 0; i < ABC.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('button', value = ABC[i]);
                letter.innerHTML = ABC[i];
                letter.setAttribute("id", "id" + i);
letter.onclick = function (e) {
                    mainForm.result.value += "" + e.target.innerHTML;
                };
                document.body.append(letter);
}
```

При нажатии на одну из кнопок должны скрыться элементы между под индексами 26-31, я попробовал решить проблему следующим образом:

```
eng.onclick = function (eng) {
for (var j = 26; j < ABC[i]; j++) {
                         document.getElementById('id' + j).hidden = true;
                    }
}
```

Но, как вы могли понять, ничего не работает. Возможно кто-то знает причину? Либо любой другой возможный способ.
Буду благодарен.

Comment: нет свойства hidden, есть стиль

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var j = 26; j < ABC.length; j++) {
                        ^^^^^^^
```

```js
function toggle() {
  let test = document.getElementById("test");
  test.hidden = !test.hidden;
  console.log(test.hidden);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">TEST</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">Click</button>
```

Comment: @IRonny Вы не с тем сравниваете `j` в условии цикла.

Comment: Как всегда - вы просто невероятны. Наверное, если б не вы, я так и сидел бы ещё очень долго. Спасибо, проблема опять была настолько глупой, что стыдно за себя. Сейчас все работает. Благодарю вас!